# Basis for time step related instability in physics engine

Tags: simulations

I've seen plenty of videogames where if the frames-per-second goes too high, the stability of the physics engine breaks down and lots of odd things like bouncing and erratic jittering/snapping behavior can occur.

Is this related to integration error [wrong term?] from different step sizes, or is there another effect at play? I've seen something akin to this when I made a 2-D version of Kerbal Space Program for fun, and noticed that when I changed step sizes, the planets would result in wildly different trajectories. [Though this could be a different phenomenon.]

I've read multiple forum posts online on this and none of them are derived from actual experience or physics--just wild guesses. I'm looking for actual code/physics/math basis for this sensitivity to step size.

I would imagine that at high frame rates, with physics engines based on time deltas [getting smaller and smaller] between frames, "could" end up having values that either hit the bottom of floats acceptable range, or far worse, get divided by that floating point error creating large numbers, which would then add into the system and if not damped out, oscillate or diverge? Though, going from 30 FPS to say, even 120 FPS, is only a factor-of-4 increase so that would mean the original simulation was *very* sensitive to time step size. But this could be a red herring and not the actual problem.

[edit] Further research appears we're talking about time-step sensitivity for a Sequential Impulse solver for Rigid Body Dynamics/simulation. As it seems (<-assumption) that many/most/all games are using a "sequential impulse solver" instead of solving all constraints at once, as that would not be performative.

Comment: I would put my bet in numerical cancellation like you mentioned, but I am interested to see what others reply

Comment: The reasons for such problems will depend on the details of the program and will be different for different programs.  So a more specific question seems necessary.

Comment: This really is not a physics question, but one of programming and task scheduling.

Comment: One possible contributor to errors is not using a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), so the sim doesn't conserve energy.

Comment: And this is why the physics engine should be decoupled if possible from drawing the display

Answer (score 1):

Really curious about the phenomenon you have observed. The sequential impulse method is invented by Erin catto, and well implemented in bullet engine and box2d.It should offer a convergence to the solution of Linear complementary problem(LCP) after enough iterations.

1. If the FPS is too high, its iterations may not be enough to get convergent.
2. On the other hand, this is a gauss seidel style method, which makes the solution order-dependent, another source of instability.
3. Another possible problem is in the Collision handling, in fast speed Righd body simulation, it is easy to get penetrated without a CCD. Then in order to correct this penetration, some other work maybe done, which cause instability.
4. Also, most Rigid body simulations in game engine is at most one semi implicit euler step, which cause its energy greater. It is also an source of evil.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).